# Simplifying a complex c# list within a list

Tags: c#, list

I have a

```
List<List<float>>
```

that contains 8 floats per inner list with varying values. The goal is to extract the position of the float with the largest value from the inner list. The end result would be one list with all of these integers (representing a position 1-8).

How could I accomplish this task in an efficient way, this is my first time trying to compact this data and I'm not sure how to approach this problem since position of the float within the list of list is the value of interest.

I was thinking that one way would be to first combine the lists and create a function that compares them 8 numbers at a time and creates a new list entirely. I feel this would be ineffective and slow.

```
list = listOfList.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
 ~function
```

Comment: First i would try to find which inner list actually contains the biggest float, then apply the size based indexing on that list

Comment: Just to clarify your question; end result would be the numbers themselves or the position of the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "efficient" I don't know if you mean the least code or fastest. @RBT's answer is more or less the least code, but procedural code is usually faster than functional code (i.e. LINQ). If you're looking for the fastest code it can't be done faster than looking at each number, like this:

```
var maxList = new List<float>(); 
var positions = new List<int>(); //if you want to store their positions
foreach(List<float> l in myList){
    var max = Single.MINVALUE; //or 0 if they're all positive
    var count = 0;
    var pos = 0;
    foreach (float f in l){
        if(f > max){
            max = f;
            pos = count;
        }
        count++;
    }
    maxList.add(max);
    positions.add(pos);
}
```

Of course the speed only matters if your lists are huge. If they are small either method will take place in milliseconds.

Comment: Nice answer. Indeed your solution is better than mine. In order to get the index of the max value in the inner list, my solution would be O(n^2) in worst case while your solution is O(n). Thumbs up! I'm very sure that LINQ can't optimize it while applying the lambda expression though not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the LINQ query which should do the work for you:

```
List<float> mylist1 = new List<float> { 1, 2 };
List<float> mylist2 = new List<float> { 3, 4 };
List<List<float>> mergedList = new List<List<float>> { mylist1, mylist2 };

//get the largest float inside each inner list and create a list
var maxOfAllInnerLists = mergedList.Select(x => x.IndexOf(x.Max()));
```

The final list `maxOfAllInnerLists` contains {1,1}.

Index of maximum element `2` in `mylist1` is `1`.
Index of maximum element `4` in `mylist2` is again `1`. Hence the output.